# adding last value to the top of the data frame.

Tags: r

the last values is 12, i want to move the last to the first value. 
that mean i want to append the data frame and move the last to the top of the data frame while moving the earlier values down. 
please check the expected output.

R code:

```
a <- c(11,243,121,42,12)
a <- data.frame(a)

    a
1  11
2 243
3 121
4  42
5  12
```

expected output:

```
a
12
11
243
121
42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `head` and `tail`, where we `rbind` the last row and then first `n-1` row together.

```
rbind(tail(a, 1), head(a,-1))

     a
#5  12
#1  11
#2 243
#3 121
#4  42
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
a[c(nrow(a), 1:(nrow(a) - 1)), , drop = FALSE]
#    a
#5  12
#1  11
#2 243
#3 121
#4  42
```

We reorder the rows according to this vector, i.e. last row goes first, then first, then second row etc.

```
c(nrow(a), 1:(nrow(a) - 1)
#[1] 5 1 2 3 4
```

`drop = FALSE` is needed (here) because `a` contains only 1 column and the reuslt would be a vector. Skip the argument when you have more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
a[c(1,dim(a)[1]),] <- a[c(dim(a)[1],1),]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use indexing with `seq_len`

```
a[c(nrow(a), seq_len(nrow(a)-1)),, drop = FALSE]
#    a
#5  12
#1  11
#2 243
#3 121
#4  42
```